# Python 3 How to ignore errors when writing UTF-8 to file

Tags: python, utf-8

I have the following program:

```
with open(r'C:\s_f.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as outf:
    with open(r'C:\street.csv', 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
        for line in f:
            out_line = line
            out_line = out_line.replace('"','¬')
            out_line = out_line.replace(',','~')
            outf.write(out_line)
```

For some reason I am still getting:

```
File "c:\Program Files\Anaconda3\streets.py", line 5
    SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xac' in file c:\Program Files\Anaconda3\streets.py on line 5, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

How can I ignore the UTF-8 errors in Python 3?

Comment: Read Python's [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have saved your source code as something other than UTF-8, most likely as Latin-1 or Windows Codepage 1252.

Your options are to change encoding used for the source (using your text editor), declare the source code encoding on the first or second line of your source file (as indicated by the error message), or use an ASCII-safe escape sequence.

The latter can be done here by using using a `\xhh` or `\uhhhh` escape sequence:

```
out_line = out_line.replace('"','\xAC')  # or `'\u00AC'`
```

`\xac` or `\x00ac` (case insensitive) encodes the same character in the Unicode standard, the [U+00AC NOT SIGN codepoint](https://codepoints.net/U+00ac). If properly encoded to UTF-8, this would use the `C2 AC` byte sequence, but your `.py` file was saved with `AC` *only* at that point.

If you do know the encoding used but don't want to change it, add a [PEP 263 comment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) to the start of your file (first or second line at the top):

```
# coding=cp1252
```

Your **best** option is to configure your code editor to save the file as UTF-8, however. That's the default encoding Python 3 will use to read your source code.

This has otherwise nothing to do with writing to the CSV file, Python can't even begin to run your code as it can't read the source properly.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

As first line of your code

Comment: The OP is using Python 3, the **default** is UTF-8. The issue is that they didn't use UTF-8 to save the source code.